# Is it necessary to unsubscribe from a combineLatest within a forkJoin?

Tags: rxjs

According to the RXJS documentation itself, from what I understood, the forkJoin, when finishing all the calls, it gives `completed()`, which automatically unsubscribes, with this it is not necessary to manually unsubscribe.

But what if I have a combineLatest that is signing something, like this:

```
 forkJoin({
      xSubject: this.serviceX.on(),
      ySubject: this.serviceY.on(),
      zSubject: this.serviceZ.on(),
      wSubject: this.serviceW.on()
    })
    .pipe(
      switchMap(({ xSubject, ySubject, zSubject, wSubject }) => {
        return combineLatest([xSubject, ySubject, zSubject, wSubject]);
      })
    )
    .subscribe(([x, y, z, w]) => {
      console.log(x)
      console.log(y)
      console.log(z)
      console.log(w)
    });
```

Is it necessary to unsubscribe from it? What is the best way in this case, if necessary?

Comment: What is the point of using a combineLatest after the  forkJoin? It will emit the same values, but in a new unecessary subscription

Comment: Previous developers created a restFul request to get the Subjects, these subjects are in fact the topic signature of the websocket, this unfortunately I cannot change. @caio oliveira

Comment: @CaioOliveira: The `combineLatest` doesn't emit the same values as `forkJoin`. The `forkJoin` emits observables which are then subscribed to using the `combineLatest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, it's always better to close subscriptions, even for functions like `forkJoin` and Angular HTTP Observables that emits once and completes. There are multiple factors that could leave the subscriptions open.

In your case specifically, the inner observable is not closed automatically. So you'd need to close it. Notice in the following snippet, the `complete` is only logged after the `close` observable has emitted, which inturn manually closes the subscription using the `takeUntil` opeartor.

```js
const { of, forkJoin, combineLatest, Subject } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, takeUntil } = rxjs.operators;

const obsX = new Subject();
const obsY = new Subject();
const obsZ = new Subject();
const obsW = new Subject();
const close = new Subject();

forkJoin({
  xSubject: of(obsX),
  ySubject: of(obsY),
  zSubject: of(obsZ),
  wSubject: of(obsW),
})
  .pipe(
    switchMap(({ xSubject, ySubject, zSubject, wSubject }) => {
      return combineLatest([xSubject, ySubject, zSubject, wSubject]);
    }),
    takeUntil(close)
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: ([x, y, z, w]) => {
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y);
      console.log(z);
      console.log(w);
    },
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
  });

setTimeout(() => obsX.next('x value'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => obsY.next('y value'), 2000);
setTimeout(() => obsZ.next('z value'), 3000);
setTimeout(() => obsW.next('w value'), 4000);

setTimeout(() => close.next(), 6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using operators like switchMap it is very important to differentiate between outer subscription (in your code example `forkJoin`) and the inner subscription (in your case `combineLatest`). The subscription on the inner example is triggered by the outer subscription, aka. whenever `forkJoin` emits something, `switchMap` is triggered and it will subscribe to `combineLatest`. Therefore just because the outer subscription is complete or even unsubscribe, that does not affect the inner subscription, so yes you would need to unsubscribe.

Nicholas Jamieson also talk about this in his blog post https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/

Comment: Possible typo: "`switchMap` is triggered and it will _subscribe_ to `combineLatest`"